# nosetests coverage report skipping some .py files and not sure why

Tags: python, nose, coverage.py

I'm running a nosetests command that results in strange results.  See image: for details: [folder structure and coverage results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuXDy.jpg)

Why aren't the files under the customercard_source/objects folder being reported in the first nosetests run?  If I manually add customercard_source to the list of packages then these files do get reported but then I end up with a duplication of the files under the resources folder as is also shown in the image.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Coverage will include files that it believes can be imported.  You need to have `__init__.py` files in folders for the contents of the folder to be importable.  Make sure you have `__init__.py` files (they can be empty) in all the right places.

And BTW, if you don't have to use nose, don't. It's unmaintained.  Pytest is a good option.

Comment: I believe I have all of the init files in the correct places.  That's why I'm so confused as to why this isn't working as expected.  Can you take a look at my folder structure in the attached image and tell me what I'm doing wrong, please?  Much appreciated...

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that you included the layout in the original question. It does look like you have them all. Are you modifying sys.path? Coverage seems to find the same file through two different file paths?